# Problem in detecting of all objects in pictures using Faster R-CNN

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to detect the  tree species in an images using Faster R-CNN Inception ResNet V2 1024x1024. Problem is that the model cannot detect all the trees in an image. setting the value of first_stage_max_proposals to 1500, only slightly helps. Also adjusting the values of grid_anchor_generator, max_detections_per_class and max_total_detections has not significant effect. Can anyone help me ? Which parameters should I adjust ?

Here is my model config file and one image where model missed most of the trees
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXbyR.jpg)

```html
# Faster R-CNN with Inception Resnet v2 (no atrous)
# Sync-trained on COCO (with 8 GPUs) with batch size 16 (800x1333 resolution)
# Initialized from Imagenet classification checkpoint
# TF2-Compatible, *Not* TPU-Compatible
#
# Achieves 39.6 mAP on COCO

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 7
    image_resizer {
        fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 867
    width: 867
  }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_keras'
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales:[0.1,0.4,0.45,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.90,1.0,
                1.2,1.25,1.3,1.35,1.4,1.45,1.5,1.6,1.8,1.90,1.95,2.0,
                2.2,2.25,2.3,2.35,2.4,2.45,2.5,2.6,2.8,2.90,2.95,3.0,
                3.2,3.25,3.3,3.35,3.4,3.45,3.5,3.6,3.8,3.90,3.95,4.0,
                4.2,4.25,4.3,4.35,4.4,4.45,4.5,4.6,4.8,4.90,4.95,5.0,
                5.2,5.25,5.3,5.35,5.4,5.45,5.5,5.6,5.8,5.90,5.95,6.0,
                6.2,6.25,6.3,6.35,6.4,6.45,6.5,6.6,6.8,6.90,6.95,7.0,
                7.2,7.25,7.3,7.35,7.4,7.45,7.5,7.6,7.8,7.90,7.95,8.0,
                8.2,8.25,8.3,8.35,8.4,8.45,8.5,8.55,8.6,8.8,8.90,8.95,9.0
                ]
        aspect_ratios: [0.2,0.5,0.75,1.0,1.25,1.3,1.35,1.4,1.45,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.75,1.8,1.9,1.95,2.0,2.25,2.5,2.75,3.0,3.5,4.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.4
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 17
    maxpool_kernel_size: 1
    maxpool_stride: 1
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.25
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 700
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 2
  num_steps: 25000
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.0008
          total_steps: 25000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.00001
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  }

train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "images/labelmap.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "images/labelmap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "test.record"
  }
}
```